# Neighbours from point connections

Tags: python, performance, numpy, computational-geometry, clustering

I am working with a mesh of triangles (in 3D, although I doubt it makes a difference). The mesh is given as list of lists, each list containing the indices of the three vertices of a triangle in said mesh.

For example:

```
0 2 6
0 12 15
2 66 10234
```

I want to find the neighbours of each point, i.e., to have an array where the first row contains the neighbours of point 0, the second the neighbours of point 1 and so on.

How do I make it more efficient?

`points` is a list of lists containing the point coordinates, while `triangles` is a list of lists containing the triangles in the mesh:

```
from numpy import ma

pointsNb = points.shape[0]

trianglesNb = triangles.shape[0]

neighbours = [[] for i in range(pointsNb)] # for each point in points, make a list of its neighbours


# find neighbours
for i in range(0, trianglesNb):
    triangle = ma.array(triangles[i][:], mask=False)
    for j, point in enumerate(triangles[i]):
        triangle[j] = ma.masked
        for possible_neighbour in triangle[~triangle.mask]:
            if possible_neighbour not in neighbours[point]:
                neighbours[point].append(possible_neighbour)
        triangle[j] = point
```

Comment: Please add a definition of `ma`.

Comment: ma is the masked property for arrays in numpy

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no documentation. What is this code supposed to do? How am I supposed to call it?
2. There's no functional decomposition. Code is easier to understand and test if it's organized into functions with well-defined inputs and outputs.
3. There's no inherent order to the neighbours of a point, so the natural representation of the neighbours is a `set`, not a `list`. Also, if you used a `set`, then you'd have a more efficient membership test, and you could update it with new points without having to check whether they are already present.

So I would write:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_neighbours(triangles):
    """Given an array of triangles (triples of points), return a graph in
    adjacency representation: that is, a map from point to the set of
    its neighbours.

    """
    graph = defaultdict(set)
    for x, y, z in triangles:
        graph[x].update((y, z))
        graph[y].update((x, z))
        graph[z].update((x, y))
    return graph
```